# User control in Data template not shown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Renderer" ItemsSource="{Binding RendererItems}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DropDownItemTemplate}" SelectedIndex="0">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" 
             MethodName="RendererItemsSelectionChanged"/>                               
          </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

And this Data Template for the items

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <UserControl Content="{Binding Icon}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And the data comes from:

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItemModel> RendererItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItemModel>();
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            RendererItems.Add(new ComboBoxItemModel() { Icon = new RenderedIcon(), Text = "Rendered" });
            RendererItems.Add(new ComboBoxItemModel() { Icon = new WireframeIcon(), Text = "Wireframe" });
            RendererItems.Add(new ComboBoxItemModel() { Icon = new ShadedIcon(), Text = "Shaded" });
            RendererItems.Add(new ComboBoxItemModel() { Icon = new HiddenLinesIcon(), Text = "Hidden Lines" });
        }
```

The ComboBoxItemModel class is defined like this:

```
    public class ComboBoxItemModel
    {
        public UserControl Icon { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }        
    }
```

The first time that I click on the Combo is shown like this:

[image]

As you can see the selected item have no Icon

The second time that I click on the Combo is shown like this:

[image]

Now the item that I have selected have no Icon. But I want that Combo items **always** have an Icon.

Comment: Why is your view-model property declared as an instance of your user control? It should be declared as a type that can be assigned to the user control's `Content` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIElement - like your `UserControl Icon` - can only have one parent element and can therefore only appear once in a visual tree. You should not have a UIElement at all as a view model data item.

In order to model an icon, use a bitmap or a drawing in a DrawingImage:

```
public class ComboBoxItemModel
{
    public ImageSource Icon { get; set; } // assign a DrawingImage
    public string Text { get; set; }        
}
```

with

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" .../>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

An alternative with a UserControl Icon might be to fill a Rectangle with a VisualBrush:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="24" Height="24">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Icon}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" .../>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: But the "Icon" is not an image is a user control which inside have a lot of things. How can I do it with a user control?

Comment: See the edited answer for how this might perhaps be done with a UserControl Icon.